# Angularjs does not pass scope.watch value to another controller when cache:false

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

Angular js is not passing scope.watch values to other controller, when I use cache:false in app.js. I can pass the value when I don't use cache:false. Please help someone

```
.state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```